# Why doesn't the regex ^([0|1]1)+$ match the string "111"?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match binary strings where every odd character is a `1`.

I came up with this:

```
^([0|1]1)+$
```

My logic:

`^` matches the start of the line

`(` starts a capture group

`[0|1]` match a `0` or `1` (since the 0th position is even)

`1` the previous character (`0` or `1`) must be followed by a `1`

`+` repeat the previous pattern one or more times

`$` matches the end of the line

So by my logic, it the above regex should match binary strings where every other character (with the first "other" character being the second one in the string) is a `1`.

However, it doesn't work correctly. As an example, the string `111` is not matched.

Why isn't it working and what should I change to make it work?

[Regex101 Test](http://regex101.com/r/oA3gN0/1)

Comment: You don't need `|` in character classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is for even-length strings only. `[01]` and `1` each match a character, therefore your capturing group matches 2 characters.

This modifies your regex to accept odd-length strings:

```
^([01](1|$))+$
```

Comment: +1 Oops, beat mine. Dunno why people downvoted. They downvote for a yes or a no, go figure =/

Answer (score 4):

If you need every odd character to be a `1`, then you need something more like this:

```
^([01]1)*[01]?$
```

The first character can be anything, the next has to be `1`, then repeated several times while the last character can be 0 or 1.

The pipe in your character class is not needed, and is actually making your regex also match a pipe character. So remove it entirely. You use the pipe in groups (i.e. `(?: ... )` or `( ... )` to denote alternation).

The above will also match an empty string, so you could add `(?=.)` at the beginning to force matching at least 1 character (i.e. `^(?=.)([01]1)*[01]?$`.

The above will match where you have (where `x` is either 0 or 1):

```
x
x1
x1x
x1x1
x1x1x
x1x1x1
```

etc.

Your current regex on the other side is attempting to match even number of characters. You repeat the group `([0|1]1)` which matches 2 characters exactly (no more no less) so the length of your whole match will be a multiple of 2.

Adding the optional `[01]` at the end allows for strings with odd number of characters to match.

Comment: Perhaps the final `1` should be optional.

Comment: @MattBall No, I was misunderstanding the question completely. Fixed it now.

Comment: This is one of the (very) few correct expressions in these answers. But apparently the downvoters have gone and won't reverse their votes...

Comment: @xsc Thanks for the support. I see NPE just changed his regex as well, which works just like mine. And yes, people downvote and forget and I'm almost sure they didn't understand the question themselves ^^;

Comment: @Jerry I've reverted my downvote and gave you an upvote after your edits.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `[0|1]` should read `[01]`. Otherwise you have a character group that matches, `0`, `|` or `1`.

Now, `[01]1` matches exactly two characters. Thus `([01]1)+` cannot match a string whose length is not a multiple of two.

To make it work with inputs of odd length, change the regex to

```
^(([01]1)+[01]?|1)$
```

Comment: not the downvoter but maybe because of this part of OPs question: "(since the 0th position is even)"?

Comment: @xsc: Thanks, but I don't quite follow. Could you please post a specific counter-example where this regex doesn't do what you think it should do?

Comment: Not the downvoter (lol, I was the first to be sent two DVs in a row) but `101` matches while the second character should be a `1`.

Comment: @NPE: it accepts 101 but every character at an odd index should be 1. OP states that the first position has index 0, thus the second character may not be 0.

Comment: @xsc: Thanks, I think I follow now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
^1?([01]1)+$|^1$
```

or

```
^(1?([01]1)+|1)$
```

To deal with an odd or even number of digits you need to put an optional `1?` at the begining. To ensure that there is at least one digit, you can't use a `*` quantifier for the group, otherwhise the pattern can match the empty string. This why, you need to use `+` for the group and add the case of a single `1`